# Heroku file upload

Tags: heroku, cloud

I'm new to Heroku and I'm looking for a way to upload a bunch of images to my application's directory. Is there a proper way of doing this, like a ssh, or a filesystem access, or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but I would just add them to the git and upload them like all other documents. Like so:

```
git push heroku master
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That would do it.

Comment: Glad I could help!